# Is it possible to manage R sessions?

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

Is it possible to manage R sessions, as in:

- Connect your R console to an existing R session process?
- Can two R sessions transfer data to one another?

One might desire this in the following **likely** scenario:

1. You're happily working on your R project and have generated data that took 3 hours to compute.
2. You decide to save your workspace in the case of a technical issue.
3. Upon saving your Rstudio decides to hang for eternity, however, leaving the R session unaffected.

In this scenario, you would want to

1. Connect to the R session with a terminal to retrieve your data anyway.
2. Setup another new R session that continuously synchronizes with the existing R session as a backup session.

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Connect your R console to an existing R session process?

Not possible.

> Can two R sessions transfer data to one another?

Yes, there are multiple ways to do this. The general keyword for this is “inter-process communication”. You can use files, named pipes or sockets, for example. To serialise the data you can use either builtin functions (`saveRDS`, `readRDS`) or packages (e.g. [feather](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feather/index.html)).

But for your given use-case, there’s a much simpler solution:

Never rely on RStudio to save your R session. Instead, do so explicitly by calling `saveRDS` (or, to save the whole workspace, which I don’t generally recommend, `save.image`). In fact, the general recommendation is to *disable the RStudio options for saving and restoring the session!*

Make sure that your preferences look like this:

[image: RStudio preferences]